# Findbugs doesn't detect exposing of the internal representation by user-defined classes

Tags: java, immutability, findbugs

When in class definition there are mutable private fields, and getters/setters that expose them, we get exception look like:

```
[INFO] path.getInsertDate() may expose internal representation by returning Ttt.insertDate path.Ttt] At Ttt.java:[line 119]
```

I've added a mutable class:

```
public class Test {
    public String test;
}
```

added private field of this Test class and getters/setters. But finbugs ingores it.

```
public class ExposingTest { 
    private Test test;

    //No warning here.
    public Test getTest() {
         return test;
    } 
}
```

Why for this warning Findbugs checks only java standard library classes, but not user-defined classes? Is there a way to control this?

Comment: "Why it checks only Java classes for this error, but not custom classes?" - Your custom classes are not written in Java? maybe that explains it. I don't really understand what you are asking and what the relation is between the error your posted and the code you posted.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt: I mean: Why it checks only java se standard library classes for this error, but not custom classes?

Comment: `Ttt.java` is not a Java SE standard library class. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Findbugs generates this warning for predefined set of classes.

Findbugs's purpose is to warn developers on potential problems with code. Findbugs doesn't check for immutability.

Mutable class per se, is not a bug or a problem. Mutable class might be a valid design choice.

```
public class Person {
    private Department dep;

    public void setDepartment(Department dep) {
        this.dep = dep;
    }
}

public class Department { 
    private String name;
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

For me it'd be extremely annoying if Findbugs started to generate warnings on each and every mutable class.

Instead of this, Findbugs tries to find potential problems, mutable classes that developers tend to overlook. Here is the method Findbugs uses to detect problematic mutable classes (in the class `edu.umd.cs.findbugs.detect.MutableStaticFields`):

```
static boolean mutableSignature(String sig) {
    return sig.equals("Ljava/util/Hashtable;") || 
            sig.equals("Ljava/util/Date;") ||
            sig.equals("Ljava/sql/Date;") ||
            sig.equals("Ljava/sql/Timestamp;") ||
            sig.charAt(0) == '[';
}
```

So, Findbugs will generate this type of warnings (internal representation exposure) for methods that return:

- Hashtable;
- Dates (`java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Timestamp`);
- Array

Findbugs doesn't even produce this warning for lists and sets.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use java.util.Date as return type in path.getInsertDate() 
String, primitive wrappers (Long, Short, ...) are immutable objects. It is safe return and share them. But Date is differ store. It has methods to mutate. It is fixed in Java 8 by introducing new Joda API. You can:
 - migrate to new API
 - ignore this warning
 - return new Date object every time 
 - return date as long